# Can one prove that the fundamental group of the circle is $\mathbb Z$ without using covering spaces?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am curious if there is a decent "bare hands" proof that the fundamental group of $S^1$ is $\mathbb Z$ that does not invoke covering space theory.

One must show two claims. First, that $f(t)=e^{2\pi i t}$ generates the fundamental group. Second, that no power of $f(t)$ is nullhomotopic.

The first claim is not hard to do by hand. It follows from an exercise in chapter 1.1 of Hatcher's textbook, and is also shown in the last chapter of Ahlfors's complex analysis textbook.

The second claim is the hard part. In fact, Ahlfors proves this too. We observe that 
$$\int_{f^m} \frac{dz}{z} = 2\pi i m,$$
which is zero if and only if $m=0$. Here we use the fact that path integrals are homotopy invariant.

I was wondering if a more direct approach to this second claim exists that does not involve complex analysis. I could not find anything in the texts I have available. May's notes give the covering space proof, and tom Dieck's book gives what looks like a more sophisticated version of the covering space proof using groupoids. Rotman also uses a complex analysis approach.

Comment: I'm sorry: is there a mathematical object called [groupie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupie)? Do you mean *groups*?

Comment: @A.P. My autocorrect changed "groupoid" to "groupie." My apologies for the mix up.

Comment: No problem. It just seemed too funny to be true...

Comment: I used to think of myself as a mapping class groupie.

Comment: I'm only too well known as a groupoid groupie! Too bad!

Comment: I have to mark up this question because I sense the same irritation I had in 1965 when writing a text,  that the usual van Kampen Theorem did not compute the fundamental group of the circle, which is **THE** basic example in algebraic topology, So one made in essence a detour to covering spaces to get this value. All unaesthetic! Then I was led to the groupoid arguments by reading a paper of Higgins. This felt good to me, and a meeting with George Mackey in 1967 showed me some  wider possibilities in extending from groups to groupoids.

Comment: $S^1$ is a topological group so $\pi_1(S^1)$ is abelian, so by the Hurewicz theorem it suffices to compute $H_1(S^1)$. All of this can be done without covering spaces.

Comment: @JustinYoung True, but that involves a considerable amount of theory.

Comment: Well, I think it's clear you need some theory, it's not a trivial problem.

Comment: If you just want to show that the first Z-cohomoogy of the circle has no torsion, you can use a Mayer-Vietoris sequence rather than an integral. BTW: The integral of dz/z assumes that the curve is piecewise differentiable so you need to show that every homotopy class contains a piecewise differentiable curve.

Comment: @JoeS I do not understand your remark. Here we are concerned about homotopy, not cohomology. And the fact that every homotopy class contains a differentiable curve follows from the first claim I mentioned -- all we need to check in the second step is that no non-zero power of the generator is nullhomotopic.

Comment: Homotopy classes of maps of compact oriented n-manifolds into the n-sphere are classified by their Brouwer degree. This can be defined purely using basic topology and calculus, no covering spaces, no integrals. $\pi_1(S^1)$ is the case of maps of a 1 manifold into the 1 sphere. The homotopy classes are in 1-1 correspondence with their Brouwer degree and every integer is the degree of some map. One then shows that mapping homotopy classes to degree is actually a homomorphism.

Comment: @Potato If a piece wise smooth curve is not null homologous then it can not be null homotopic. The integral of dz/z will be non-zero if the real homology class if the curve is not zero. Your proof that there is no torsion in π1(S1) shows that the real homology class of a path is zero iff it is null homotopic. For other manifolds there will be curves that are null homologous but not null homotopic. The group of closed 1-forms detects whether they are null homologous in real homology. So there may be non-null homotopic paths for which every integral of every closed 1-form is zero.

Comment: I think that the covering space proof, given without using the words "covering space," is more barehanded than using complex analysis, homology theory, or groupoids. You have to show that every curve and homotopy of curves in $S^1$ lifts to $\mathbb{R}$, observe that the difference of lifts of endpoints of a closed curve is a homotopy invariant integer, observe that all paths in $\mathbb{R}$ are homotopic with endpoints fixed, and give examples of curves with each integer invariant. The only technical tool required is the Lebesgue covering lemma, to permit constructing lifts piecewise.

Comment: @Kevin Carlson It just seems a pity while doing this not to prove a theorem which does so much more, since you need  to do the orthodox van Kampen theorem anyway. If you do the version for $\pi_1(X,C)$, for $C$ is a set of base points, you also should develop enough of the algebra of groupoids to exploit this result. Why not at least let students know there is such a result?

Comment: @RonnieBrown I certainly would, if I were teaching the course. I was just responding to the request for a "barehanded" proof without commenting on which of the proofs that use machinery is preferable.

Answer (score 13):

A version of the Seifert-van Kampen theorem for not necessarily connected spaces was published by me in **1967**, see [here](https://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/brownvk.pdf), and it uses the fundamental groupoid $\pi_1(X,C)$ on a **set** $C$ of base points. The usual connectivity condition is replaced for a pushout determined by $U \cup V$  by the condition that $C$ meets each path component of $U,V, U \cap V$. You can ask if this method is "bare hands"!

In a sense, the thesis proposed in 1968, maybe not explicitly,  is that **all of $1$-dimensional homotopy theory** is better modelled by groupoids rather than groups.

The book [Topology and Groupoids](https://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html) gives a full account of this theory; it  is the 2006 3rd  edition of a book published in 1968, 1988. See also this [mathoverflow discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one), and this reprinted 1971 book [Categories and Groupoids](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/7/tr7abs.html) by Philip   Higgins. A feature of these books is the groupoid construction $U_f(G)$ with object set $Y$ from a groupoid $G$ and a set function $f: Ob(G) \to Y$. This construction includes free groups and free groupoids, and free products of groups. I'll take this opportunity to advertise a small [correction](https://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/brouwer-cor-fin.pdf) to the proof of the Jordan Curve Theorem in T&G: this proof applies groupoid algebra to unions of non-connected spaces.

Alexander Grothendieck wrote in a letter to me in 1983:

" . .... both the choice of a base point, and the $0$-connectedness assumption, however innocuous they may seem at first sight, seem to me of a very essential nature.  To make an analogy, it would be just impossible to work at ease with algebraic varieties, say, if sticking from the outset (as had been customary for a long time) to varieties which are supposed to be connected. Fixing one point, in this respect (which wouldn't have occurred in the context of algebraic geometry) looks still worse, as far as limiting elbow-freedom goes!"

[Here is a [link](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~georges.maltsiniotis/ps.html) to further post 1970 correspondence of Alexander Grothendieck.]

June 10: I should have said from the start that my work on generalisations of the Seifert-van Kampen Theorem for the fundamental group was motivated by the desire to obtain  a result which would also yield the fundamental group of the circle. I first  extended a method of nonabelian cohomology due to Olum, and this was published in 1965, see [here](https://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/olum.pdf): it gave the fundamental group of a wedge of circles. To my surprise, I then found that the direct method using the fundamental groupoid on a set of base points was both simpler to prove and was more powerful. The cited 1967 paper on that also refers to a paper of Weinzweig, which uses nerves of covers.

The following diagram is another way of looking at the fundamental group of the circle.

[image: pushouts]

Here the groupoid $\mathsf I$ has two objects $0,1$ and one arrow $\iota: 0 \to 1$, and is easily shown to be isomorphic to $\pi_1([0,1],\{0,1\})$.

Nov 17, 2015: I leave the reader to work out how to modify the second  diagram if you replace $\{0,1\}$ by $\{0,1,2\}$, $[0,1]$ by $[0,2]$,  $S^1$ by $S^1 \vee S^1$, ..... and ....

February 16, 2017 A recent account of the background to and developments of this work is in [this article](https://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/brouwer-honor.pdf).

April, 2020 See also my  answer  to this [mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one) on using more than one base point for the Van Kampen Theorem. For the circle, it seems like a Goldilocks situation: one base point is too small; the whole fundamentaal groupoid is too big; but two base points are just right!

More generally, what is wrong with a connected space which is the union of $50$ open sets  the intersection of any two of which has at least $200$ pathcomponents? The algebraic theory of groupoids is a natural extension of the theory of groups, available for over half a century.

Comment: I have read things in "Topology and Groupoids" and cannot withhold myself frome recommending it.

Answer (score 5):

There is a purely topological definition of winding number in the plane that involves neither covering spaces nor complex analysis.  Let $H_0$, $H_1$, $H_2$, an $H_3$ be the half-planes $x>0$, $y>0$, $x<0$, and $y<0$, respectively.

Given a map $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$ with $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1) = (1,0)$, a ***mesh*** for $\gamma$ is a pair of sequences $t_0=0<t_1 < \cdots < t_k=1$ and $n_1,\ldots,n_k \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ such that $\gamma\bigl([t_{i-1},t_i]\bigr) \subset H_{n_i}$ for all $i$.  Clearly any closed curve $\gamma$ has at least one mesh.

Given a mesh for $\gamma$, the ***winding number*** of $\gamma$ is defined by
$$
w(\gamma) \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^k \Delta(n_{i-1},n_i)\qquad\text{where}\qquad \Delta(m,n) = \begin{cases} -1 & \text{if }n-m\equiv -1\;(\text{mod }4), \\
0 & \text{if }n-m\equiv 0\;(\text{mod }4), \\ 1 & \text{if }n-m\equiv 1\;(\text{mod }4). \end{cases}
$$
It is possible to show that $w(\gamma)$ does not depend on the mesh chosen, using the fact that any two meshes have a common refinement.

One can use this to prove combinatorially that any closed curve in $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ is homotopic to $e^{2\pi int}$ for some value of $n$.  This involves using homotopy to eliminate any stuttering in the sequence $n_1,\ldots,n_k$, i.e. subsequences of the form $m,n,m$ for $n\ne m$, and removing points $t_i$ to eliminate repeated pairs $n,n$.  Eventually, one gets a mesh without any stuttering or repetition, which will have the same sequence $\{n_i\}$ as a mesh for some $e^{2\pi int}$.  But any two curves having meshes with the same sequence $\{n_i\}$ are homotopic.

Next, one can prove that any two homotopic curves have the same winding number.  Specifically, suppose that $\Phi\colon [0,1]\times[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$ is a homotopy of curves, with $\Phi(0,t) = \Phi(1,t) = (1,0)$ for all $t\in[0,1]$.  If we let $1/n$ be a Lebesgue number for the covering $\bigl\{\Phi^{-1}(H_0),\Phi^{-1}(H_1),\Phi^{-1}(H_2),\Phi^{-1}(H_3)\bigr\}$, then each of the $\frac{1}{n}\times \frac{1}{n}$ subsquares of the $n\times n$ grid in the unit square maps to a single $H_i$.  Then one can give some fairly simple combinatorial arguments that the winding number is the same for each row of squares, and therefore winding number is a homotopy invariant.

Answer (score 1):

Using category theory one can show if a functor preserves finite products and terminal objects then it sends group objects to group objects. Fundamental group is such a functor from category of topological spaces to category of groups.

A group object of category of topological spaces is a topological group. A group object of groups is an abelian group. So basically this says, fundamental group of a topological group is abelian. Since circle is a topological group its fundamental group is abelian.

Also one can show first homology of a topological space is abelianization of its fundamental group. (In 2.A of Hatcher's book you can see proof of this fact). So basically fundamental group of circle is same as its first homology.

Now using cellular homology it is quite easy to show that the first homology of circle is integers, hence its fundamental group is integers.

As far as I know any of the above facts does not use covering spaces.

Note: After I wrote this answer I realized one user posted same answer in the comments. I just wanted to keep it since it has a bit more details.

Comment: The fundamental group is a functor from the category of pointed spaces to the category of groups. Grothendieck has stated that "space" and "pointed space"  should not be confused, especially for students. To restrict the Van Kampen Theorem to pointed spaces is VERY and unnecessarily restrictive. restrictive. Topological grpoups need not be connected.