# Proving that two embeddings are not homotopic

Tags: homotopy-theory

Todd Rowland [writes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomotopyClass.html): "Consider the number of ways an infinitely stretchable string can be tied around a tree trunk... For any integer n, the string can be wrapped around the tree n times, for positive $n$ clockwise, and negative n counterclockwise. Each integer n corresponds to a homotopy class of maps from $S^1$ to $S^1$."

I do not understand why every $n$ corresponds to a different homotopy class? Why can't we deform a string tied 2 times around the tree, by pulling one of its ends and tying it around the tree a third time?

What is a formal proof that

- For each $n$ there is a single class corresponding to $n$ rounds,
- For different $n$ the classes are different?

Comment: The most common proof is by considering the universal covering, which is the map $\Bbb R\to S^1$ mapping $x$ to $\exp(2\pi ix)$and using some more theory

Comment: One usually considers that the string cannot pass _through_ the tree.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319702/can-one-prove-that-the-fundamental-group-of-the-circle-is-mathbb-z-without-us