# How to prove the map $z\mapsto z^n$ is not null-homotopic without using degree theory?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $n>0$ be an integer and $f_n: S^1\rightarrow S^1$ given by

$$f_n(z)=z^n.$$

Is there a way to show $f_n$ is not null-homotopic without using degree theory?

I was looking for a proof using basic defintions only, something like: Suppose $f_n$ is null-homotopic so there exists a homotopy $H: S^1\times I\rightarrow S^1$ bettwen $f_n$ and a constant map. Then..

Thanks.

Comment: Are we allowed to use results about lifts to covering spaces?

Comment: Nope, because I should be able to explain this to someone only using the basics of homotopy theory. I didn't like to discuss more advanced topics, if it weren't needed.

Comment: Use the complex analysis definition of winding number. If you want a topological proof you are out of luck.

Comment: Try [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319702/can-one-prove-that-the-fundamental-group-of-the-circle-is-mathbb-z-without-us) for some inspiration.

Comment: You should not expect that there exists a proof using only the basics of homotopy theory. You will either need some covering space theory or some non-trivial results from complex analysis. No silver bullet ...

Answer (score 1):

Let $p:\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ the natural covering map ($p(t)=e^{2\pi it}$). We can proof this using the path lifting property for maps $f:[0,1]\to S^1$ (proved in pg. 30 in Hatcher's book for example), obtaining a map $\overset{\sim}{f}:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $p\circ \overset{\sim}{f}=f$.

The lifting for the map $f_n(t)=e^{2n\pi it}$ starting at $0$ is $\overset{\sim}{f}_n(t)=nt$. If we suppose that $f_n$ is null-homotopic, then $\overset{\sim}{f}_n$ is null-homotopic preserving end points (it is consequence of the homotopy lifting property proved again in pg. 30 in Hatcher's book), but it is impossible because $\overset{\sim}{f}_n$ is not a loop.

Answer (score 0):

$f_n$ is not null homotopic because $(f_n)_*$ is not trivial homomorphism. More than that it is injective. This can be seen easily by showing that the generator is mapped to a non trivial element. Indeed if $[α]$ is the generator then it is mapped to $[α]^{n}$.

Comment: That is essentially using degree theory